# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'text' with pyplot

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib, text, attributes

I'm not getting to add text to the pyplot chart. 'm trying to do that ...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = Teste.loc[:,['Q001', 'NU_NOTA_MT']]

plt.plot(ax['Q001'], ax['NU_NOTA_MT'], 'ro-', label = 'MTM')

#adicionando as legendas do questionário no gráfico
textdictQ002 = ""
for key,value in q001eq002Dicionario.items():
    textdictQ002 = textdictQ002 + "{k} + {v}\n".format(k=key,v=value)

ax.text(0.03, 0.65, textdictQ002, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=12,
        bbox={'boxstyle':'round', 'facecolor':'wheat', 'alpha':0.5})

plt.title("Notas x Escolaridade Pai", fontsize = 20)

plt.ylabel("Medias", size = 15)

plt.xlabel("Categorias", size = 15)

plt.legend()

plt.grid()

plt.show()
```

And error ...

[image]

My files "Teste" and "q001eq002Dicionario" are:

**Teste**

```
    Q001    SG_UF_RESIDENCIA    NU_NOTA_MT

0   A   SC  482.720461

1   B   SC  505.414095

2   H   SC  520.755467

3   C   SC  522.308284

4   D   SC  533.886299

5   E   SC  556.726944

6   F   SC  606.302340

7   G   SC  630.829501
```

**q001eq002Dicionario**

```
{'A': 'Nunca Estudou',
 'B': 'Não completou a 4º série/5º ano do ensino fundamental',
 'C': 'Completou a 4º série/5º ano, mas não completou a 8º série/9º ano do ensino fundamental',
 'D': 'Completou a 8º série/9º ano do ensino fundamental, mas não completou o ensino médio',
 'E': 'Completou o ensino médio, mas não completou a Faculdade',
 'F': 'Completou a Faculdade, mas não completou a Pós-Graduação',
 'G': 'Completou a Pós-Graduação',
 'H': 'Não sei'}
```

I appreciate any help in resolving this error

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you provided a textual representation of `Teste`. Could you please provide the definition of that table?

Comment: `ax` is a `DataFrame`, not a matplotlib `Axes`.

Comment: Teste File is a Dataframe and q001eq002Dicionario is a dictionary. I'm trying to add the dictionary as a legend on the chart.